# Rendering RichText in a Lotus Notes document

Tags: powershell, com, lotus-notes

I am trying to create documents inside a LotusNotes Database by using the COM API. So far everything is working, except for the rendering of the RichText.

The RichText is created by converting a MarkDown document to RichText using Pandoc. Afterwards, I create a new `RichTextItem`.

In PowerShell it looks like this:

```
# A LotusNotes document
$Document = $Database.CreateDocument()

# Add a Body field as type RichText
$RTI = $Document.CreateRichTextItem("Body")

# Append the RichText to the field
$RTI.AppendText("THE_CONVERTED_MARKDOWN_COMES_HERE")
$Document.Save($true, $true)
```

But when I view the document, I only see the raw unformatted RichText in the body field. How can I render the text?

Answer (score 0):

That's what AppendText does. It takes whatever you give it and renders it as plain text.

I am not familiar with Pandoc and have no idea what format is coming out of your conversion from MarkDown, but if it is HTML then you probably need to be using [NotesMIMEEntity](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESMIMEENTITY_CLASS_OVERVIEW.html) and other classes related to it.  Otherwise, investigating a third party product like the MIDAS Rich Text API from Genii Software may be your best course of action.

Comment: Pandoc converts the MarkDown into regular RichText

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find any reference to "rich text" on the Pandoc website. I think when most people say "regular rich text", they mean "Microsoft RTF format", but that's not the same as Notes Rich Text - which I believe is a few years older than the Microsoft format. If Pandoc can convert to HTML instead (and the website for Pandoc suggests that it can), Notes can deal with that using NotesMIMEEntity. Otherwise, you're probably going to need the third party code that I mentioned abobe to help you do what you want.